# Angular Observable Output: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component whose output is an observable. I've done this many times before, since Observables are structurally compatible with EventEmitters Though I can see it working by logging the outputs to the console, I still get the following RxJs error:

`You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.`

Here is the code that's causing the issue.

Child component Typescript:

```js
  @Output() score = defer(() => this.actionHistory$
    .pipe(
      map((actionHistory: Array<number>) => actionHistory.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next, 0)),
      startWith(0),
      tap(val => console.log(val)),
      tap(val => this.currentScore = val)
    )
  );

  ballClick$ = new Subject<number>();
  undoClick$ = new Subject<any>();
  
  addToScore$ = defer(() => merge(this.ballClick$, this.deadBallsAfterNine)
    .pipe(
      map((next) => (state) => [...state, next])
    )
  );
  resetScore$ = defer(() => this.resetScore
    .pipe(
      map(() => (_) => [])
    )
  );
  undoAction$ = this.undoClick$
    .pipe(
      map(() => (state: Array<number>) => state.slice(0, -1))
    );

  actionHistory$ = defer(() => merge(
      this.addToScore$,
      this.undoAction$,
      this.resetScore$
    ).pipe(
      scan((state, fn) => fn(state), []),
      startWith([])
    )
  );
```

Parent component HTML:

```html
  <app-player-score class="col-sm-4"
      [resetScore]="matchStart$"
      (score)="player1Score$.next($event)">        
  </app-player-score>
```

Parent component Typescript:

```js
  player1Score$ = new Subject<number>();
```

Comment: Do you instantiate `resetScore` to a default value? If not, I believe the fields will be instantiated before the `@Input()` is processed, meaning `resetScore` will be undefined when attempting the `pipe` call on it. Otherwise I can't reproduce with the given code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ciprod?file=src/app/test/test.component.ts

Comment: The `tap` function that logs the value to the console runs before the errors, so I don't think that's the issue. That's why I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: From that stackblitz, none of this code seems to be causing the issue. Try to introduce more until you can reproduce it.

Comment: are all of those `defer()` s necessary?!

Comment: What's `this.deadBallsAfterNine`? That is not defined in your code

Comment: Here is an updated stackblitz that shows the error in the console. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1awepy?file=src/index.html

Comment: @Mazdak is there some problem with using defer? Some of those observables are passed from the parent or dependent on composite observables that include the former.